# using streamlinejs with nodejs express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to the 'nodejs' world.So wanting to explore the various technologies,frameworks involved i am building a simple user posts system(users posting something everybody else seeing the posts) backed by redis.I am using express framework which is recommended by most tutorials.But i have some difficulty in gettting data from the redis server i need to do 3 queries from the redis server to display the posts.In which case have to use neested callback after each redis call.So i wanted to use streamline.js to simplify the callbacks.But i am unable to get it to work even after i used `npm install streamline -g` and `require('streamline').register();` before calling

```
var keys=['comments','timestamp','id'];
var posts=[];
for(var key in keys){
    var post=client.sort("posts",'by','nosort',"get","POST:*->"+keys[key],_);
    posts.push(post);
}
```

i get the error **ReferenceError: _ is not defined**.

Please point me in the right direction or point to any resources i might have missed.

Comment: Is the code you're posting located in a separate `._js` file?

Comment: yes it is located in a separate file but i have added the `require('streamline').register()` in the same file and tried it as well.

Comment: The `register` should be in a normal `.js` file, and that file should `require` the `._js` file. The error you're getting is related to the `._js` file not being run by/through streamline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `require('streamline').register()` call should be in the file that starts your application (with a `.js` extension). The streamline code should be in another file with a `._js` extension, which is required by the main script.

Streamline only allows you to have async calls (calls with `_` argument) at the top level in a main script. Here, your streamline code is in a module required by the main script. So you need to put it inside a function. Something like:

```
exports.myFunction = function(_) {
  var keys=['comments','timestamp','id'];
  var posts=[];
  for(var key in keys){
    var post=client.sort("posts",'by','nosort',"get","POST:*->"+keys[key],_);
    posts.push(post);
 }
}
```

This is because `require` is synchronous. So you cannot put asynchronous code at the top level of a script which is required by another script.

Comment: You'll also find useful info in the streamline FAQ: how to deal with evented APIs and links to packages that bridge streamline and express.